# Emberjs: show outlet on certain conditional

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to show some blocks of HTML based on the existence of an outlet. I tried this code but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

```
{{#if outlet}}
    <table class="col-sm-9">
        some content
    </table>
    <table class="col-sm-3">
        {{outlet}}
    </table>
{{else}}
    <table class="col-sm-12">
        some content
    </table>
{{/if}}
```

**EDIT:**

My scenario is if I'm on route `customers` then `outlet` is hidden, else if I'm on route `customers.create` then `outlet` is show. Is there any simple way to do it without touch `router.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried naming the outlet and then render the content of a particular outlet in the router.

Please see http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/
something like this , which is mentioned in the guide.

```
App.PostRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
      this.render('favoritePost', {   // the template to render
      into: 'posts',                // the template to render into
      outlet: 'posts',              // the name of the outlet in that template
      controller: 'blogPost'        // the controller to use for the template
  });
  this.render('comments', {
     into: 'favoritePost',
     outlet: 'comment',
     controller: 'blogPost'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: See my updated question. I don't give outlet's name before. By the way, is there any simple way to do it without touch `router.js` file?

Comment: It's what the index route is for.